# Maven creating incorrect manifest file, jar file isn't executable, because main class isn't specified

Tags: java, maven, executable-jar

I'm trying to produce a .jar file that I can execute through command prompt. I am using Maven with this project so that I can use Unirest (to get data through a realtor API). First, however, I am trying to compile a simple "hello world" program to an executable .jar file, and Maven isn't adding the main-class attribute to the Manifest file. I used the instructions on [this website](https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven) under the "Maven Assembly Plugin" section. Here's the relevant portion of the pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
         <manifest>
           <mainClass>com.javaRealtor.app.App</mainClass>
         </manifest>
       </archive>
       <descriptorRefs>
         <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
       </descriptorRefs>
     </configuration>
   </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

The .java file is located at `java-realtor\src\main\java\com\javaRealtor\app\App.java`. Do I need to specify the MainClass part of the plugin differently? I tried using just `com.javaRealtor.App` as well, but that didn't work. The manifest file (I extracted the jar to view it so I could maybe figure out what was going on) still doesn't have a line for a main class.

Comment: Specify the plugin version as follow an see if it works `<version>3.3.0</version>` under the artifact name. The fact you are not providing it may be the root cause of your problem

Comment: I suggest you use 2.3 maven shade plugin from the link you posted - I found it more reliable in the past. And as has been said, don't forget to specify the version of a plugin, and pay attention to maven output

Comment: According to their own web page on usage, you are missing a section on your pom.xml for <executions> = https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html

However, I have also had better luck with the shade plugin, when packaging spring applications.  Just remember to add transformers for the Spring configuration files that are embedded in their jar files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use shade plugin for this transformation

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.4</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <transformers>
          <transformer
            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
            <manifestEntries>
              <Main-Class>com.javaRealtor.app.App</Main-Class>
            </manifestEntries>
          </transformer>
        </transformers>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Just a note: please avoid camel case in packaging name in order to:

- avoid problem managing multiple dev platforms (case sensitive: linux/unix and case insentive Windows)
- be complain with [Java Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html)